# DaemonSet in version "v1" cannot be handled as a DaemonSet: no kind "DaemonSet" is registered for version "apps/v1"

Tags: kubernetes

Output of `kubectl create -f redis.yaml`:

> Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "redis.yaml":
>   DaemonSet in version "v1" cannot be handled as a DaemonSet: no kind
>   "DaemonSet" is registered for version "apps/v1"

What does this error indicate? How could I solve it?

**redis.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: redis
  labels:
    app: redis
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      tolerations:
        - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
          effect: NoSchedule
      containers:
        - image: redis:4.0-alpine
          name: redis
```

Answer (score 2):

The version was set too low:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
```